# Rails: Update users via link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update a devise record via a link in my view.

This is what I've have:

```
= link_to "Update", user_registration_path(current_user, user: {abc: true}), method: :put, remote: true
```

I get the following issue:

> private method `to_param' called for #

How am I able to update this record remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to do this what I do is a create a method that the link resolves to like

routes

```
resources :users do 
  match "update_abc" => "update_abc#users", :as => :update_abc, via: :get
end
```

now in your view you can do

```
users_update_abc_path(current_user, abc: true, efg: 21)
```

and in the controller

```
def update_abc
  user = user.find(params[:id])
  if params[:abc].present?
    user.abc = params[:abc]
  end
  ....
  user.save
  redirect_to :back
end
```

I hope that this helps :)

Comment: Is it possible to create a method which handles multiple attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can change the `user.update_attribute` with `user.update_attributes`

Comment: And can I pass the attributes I want to update to the method with the value attached?

Comment: I just updated the answer with passing extra values,

Comment: Now if I have 3 attributes that could get updated, but I pass only one, that'd throw an error, right?

Comment: Hm... I get the error `undefined method 'users_update_abc_path' for #<#<Class:0x126795a8>:0x126787e0>`